# vue.js Structure and Conventions

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm doing my first steps with vue.js. I would like to rebuild two php platforms that I have built in vue.js. I took two online courses at CoderCampus and already built the first structure. Header, menu and footer are built and integrated. I also manage the interactive content via router.

However, I have a few questions where I haven't found anything helpful on the net:

1. i have to load a lot of content from databases, which is also interactive. Is it better to build APIs to access the data, or is it sufficient to access the php functions directly via axios?
   Both platforms are to become PWAs. Would APIs have advantages here?
2. Within the interactive content there are various functions that, for example, refer to other content. Can this also be controlled via vue-router or are there other possibilities?
3. can data/status values within the platform structure (not to the DB) also be transmitted via POST, or only with GET? I am not a big fan of data transfer via URL.

Thank you very much!

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version). Because I was to lazy to write in english directly ;)

Comment: The question is too broad. "php functions directly via axios" - what is it supposed to look like? 2 and 3 are too unspecific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite loaded, but I'll try my best to point you towards some things.

1. It is better to have an API that can support pagination and other variable return types. I am quite unsure what you mean by "PHP functions from Axios", do you mean an endpoint that you built with PHP? Either way, if you are transitioning from PHP I would recommend building a REST API with Spring Boot (Java) or another MVC framework.
2. Vue Router is used to transition from one page to another for SPAs (single page apps) mainly. It is a very useful tool for routing the user from one page (each page being a Vue component in a way) to another. So I'd say "yes" to this.
3. You can do POST calls with Axios programmatically. If you have a simple POST that returns the status of something for example, then `axios.post(status_endpoint).then(response => response.data)` (`response.data` being the returned data from your endpoint) would give you the response data to use as you wish.